# R xgboost re-convert numbers to character

Tags: r, xgboost

I have created an xgboost model and satisfied with the accuracy.
Obviously, my "Y" are now numeric. Is there are a way to convert my predicted values to original chr?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I typically add an additional column of the original labels (i.e. "Placebo" or "Treatment" instead of "0" or "1") when I summarise my results - can you adapt this to your needs?

```
Summary_of_results <- data.frame(Patient_ID = rownames(data),
                                 label = labels, 
                                 prediction = xgbpred)
Summary_of_results$original_label <- ifelse(
  Summary_of_results$label == 0,
  "Placebo",
  "Treatment")

Summary_of_results
```